# How to write header file in C

Tags: c, macos, header-files

I'm a newbie and I'am learning the C language. I get some errors when I compile the following code.

**Constans.h**

```
#define ERROR 0   
#define TRUE 1  
#define FALSE 0  
#define OK 1  
#define INFEASIBLE -1  
#define OVERFLOW -2  
typedef int Status;
```

**ArrayList.h**

```
#include"Constans.h"  
#define LIST_INIT_SIZE 100  
#define LIST_INCREMENT 20  
typedef struct{  
int *elem;  
int length;  
int listsize;  
}SqList;  
extern Status InitList_sq(Sqlist *l);  
extern Status ListInsert_sq(Sqlist *l,int i,int e);  
extern Status ListDelete_sq(Sqlist *l,int i,int *e);  
extern void MergeList_sq(Sqlist La,Sqlist Lb,Sqlist *Lc);  
extern void ListTraverse(Sqlist l,void(*visit)(void));
```

**program.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include "ArrayList.h"  
int main(){  
return 0;  
}
```

[image]

My environment:
**OS: Mac OS X 10.9.1 version

Editor: vim

Compiler:i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2**

I'm  very sorry about my fault adding backslashs sign.

Comment: You do not need backslashes at the beginning of lines in front of the pound `#` sign.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21152539/838253

Comment: It isn't a duplicate of SO 21152539, though it is closely related.

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with an example that used the backslash notation?  I've seen a lot of odd code over the years, but I don't recall seeing that before (mainly because it is wrong and simply doesn't work). Also, you should be able to copy and paste the code from the terminal, rather than embedding an image.

Comment: What's up with the "??" in the terminal screenshot. If you're using international characters set your file encodings consistently, e.g. use utf-8 for the source as well as your terminal. Or even better just stick to ascii.

Comment: The question has been rewritten to invalidate the previously valid answers.  Originally, the question had `\#define` and `\#include` lines in the headers.  These backslashes have now been removed, leaving a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqList ≠ Sqlist
```

*unless you want unknown types in your code.

**SqList** needs to be consistent in the way it's used, otherwise it's not equal, or means the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

backslashes not needed. If you want to comment a line out use "//" instead.

Answer (score 3):

What's with the backslashes before the `\#define` etc?  Remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to escape the pound signs in your `#include` and `#define` statements. the syntax is

`#include "header.h"`

`#define THING 1`

also, I am not certain, but I always thought you needed a space between `#include` and `constants.h`. so it would not be

`#include"constants.h"`

It would be

`#include "constants.h"`

I hope this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: The spaces aren't required as pointed out by Jonathan Leffler earlier. :) ... `"Actually, the space is not necessary (the tokenizer knows how to split the lines up without the space), but it is certainly conventional to put the space there (see the standard for examples)."`

Comment: Oh, okay. I knew you could do that on commodore basic, but never really tried anywhere else.